# Unable to bind form to object

Tags: java, playframework

I am trying to build a simple crud form. I am following the examples in the play for java book. The problem is that when i submit my form it does create a new product object, however the values in the product object are set to NULL. They are not set to the values filled at the form. So in other words, the form does not seem to bind to the product class.

**Output**

```
Saved product null - null
```

**Form view html**

```
@(productForm: Form[Product]) 
@import helper._ 
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._ 

@main("Product form") {
<h1>Product form</h1>
@helper.form(action = routes.Products.save()) {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product (@productForm("name").valueOr("New"))</legend>
        @helper.inputText(productForm("ean"), '_label -> "EAN")
        @helper.inputText(productForm("name"),'_label -> "Name")
        @helper.textarea(productForm("description"), '_label ->     "Description")
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
    <a class="btn" href="@routes.Products.list()">Cancel</a>
} 
}
```

**Controller class**

```
package controllers;

import java.util.List;

import models.Product;
import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.products.list;
import views.html.products.details;

public class Products extends Controller {

public static Form<Product> productForm = Form.form(Product.class);

public static Result index() {
    return ok();
}
public static Result list() {
    List<Product> products = Product.findAll();
    return ok(list.render(products));
}

public static Result save() {
    Form<Product> boundForm = productForm.bindFromRequest();
    Product product = boundForm.get();
    product.save();
    return ok(String.format("Saved product %s", product));
}

public static Result newProduct() {
    return ok(details.render(productForm));
}

public static Result details(String ean) {
    return TODO;
}



}
```

**Product class**

```
package models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Product {

public String ean;

public String name;

public String description;

private static List<Product> products;
static {
    products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    products.add(new Product("1111111111111", "Paperclips 1",
            "Paperclips description 1"));
    products.add(new Product("2222222222222", "Paperclips 2",
            "Paperclips description "));
    products.add(new Product("3333333333333", "Paperclips 3",
            "Paperclips description 3"));
    products.add(new Product("4444444444444", "Paperclips 4",
            "Paperclips description 4"));
    products.add(new Product("5555555555555", "Paperclips 5",
            "Paperclips description 5"));
}

public Product() {
}

public Product(String ean, String name, String description) {
    this.ean = ean;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

public static List<Product> findAll() {
    return new ArrayList<Product>(products);
}

public static Product findByEan(String ean) {
    for (Product candidate : products) {
        if (candidate.ean.equals(ean)) {
            return candidate;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static List<Product> findByName(String term) {
    final List<Product> results = new ArrayList<Product>();
    for (Product candidate : products) {
        if (candidate.name.toLowerCase().contains(term.toLowerCase())) {
            results.add(candidate);
        }
    }
    return results;
}

public static boolean remove(Product product) {
    return products.remove(product);
}

public void save() {
    products.remove(findByEan(this.ean));
    products.add(this);
}

public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s - %s", ean, name);
}




 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently running `play clean` fixed it. I however do not know why.

Comment: I have run into a couple of issues that will not resolve until I run  `play clean`. It's my goto when things aren't working when I think they should.